# Copy FGDB from folder to another folder in Python 3 without ArcPy?

Tags: python-3, copy

I found this code here. first time I ran it, it copied my file to another folder but for second time nothing happened. Even I didn't get error in Jupyter Notebook.

```
#Move GDB to G: for your project's folder

src = r'folder_1'
dst = r'folder_2'

import shutil, errno

def copyanything(src, dst):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dst)
    except OSError as exc: # python >2.5
        if exc.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
            shutil.copy(src, dst)
        else: raise
```

I don't have access to ArcPy in my PC. I need something which works without ArcPy and for Python 3.

Comment: A file geodatabase is a directory with many files which represent zero or more tables. Simple filesystem calls can work to move an *entire* file geodatabse, but not a single FGDB table.

Comment: Since a file geodatabase is just a folder of files so if you are stuck copying a folder using pure Python then the place to research/ask is [so].

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a port of your code to Python3, don't think it matters that you're working with FGDB's:

```py
#Move GDB to G: for your project's folder

src = r'folder_1'
dst = r'folder_2'

import shutil

def copyanything(src, dst):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dst)
    except NotADirectoryError as e:
        shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

Shouldn't need the `errno` check as the raised error is specific enough in python3.